# what does (**variable) mean in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

at https://www.airpair.com/javascript/node-js-tutorial I see something I haven't seen before:

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(**filename); // current file
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(**dirname + '/out.gz');
```

What does the ** mean in `...(**filename);` and `...(**dirname ...);`? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo in the tutorial.

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__filename); // current file
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/out.gz');
```

They are [globals in node](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename)

Answer (score 2):

As someone else mentioned within the comment is should be `__filename` instead of 
`**filename`

**Node.js documention reference:**

[__filename Global Objects](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename)

[__dirname Global Objects](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)